# Debugging Android on Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

I've setup Netbeans using nbandroid (http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid) which has been working just fine for the last few days. I've already made a small app which runs in the emulator and even on my phone.

The thing I can't get to work is the debugger console in netbeans.
If I add these lines of code to my app nothing appears in any of the output screens in netbeans.

```
System.out.println("blaat");
Log.d("info", "blaat")
```

Even though I'm 100% sure the code should run. Any suggestions on what I might have missed?

Comment: I should have mentioned, but yes i've used adb logcat and my debug information does appear there.
However I hoped that there was I way I could make it appear in the netbeans console, neatly filtered and maybe even colored.
Something like firebug for javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just found a better solution in another question:
[Android Debugging with Logcat and Emulator. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581837/android-debugging-with-logcat-and-emulator-is-it-possible/4763346#4763346)

started using ddms, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening a new cmd prompt and type "adb logcat".