# The application has stopped unexpectedly please try again android

Tags: java, android

Every time i try launch my app it shows this error:

```
The application SMSbackupv1 (process com.SMS.Backup) has stpped unexpectedly. please try again.
```

i have no idea where the error is been created. however when i debug the file the threadGroup.class shows and it displays

```
Source not found
the JAR file C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar has no source attachment.
```

here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SMSbackup extends Activity {
    private Button backupBTN;
    public ArrayList<String> exportBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            backupBTN = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.backupBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {

                        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                                Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null,
                                null);
                        getColumnData(c);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void getColumnData(Cursor cur) {
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String id;
                String date;
                String phoneNumber;
                String body;

                int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
                int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("date");
                int numberColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("address");
                int bodyColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("body");

                do {

                    id = cur.getString(idColumn);
                    date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                    body = cur.getString(bodyColumn);
                    phoneNumber = cur.getString(numberColumn);

                    exportBuffer.add(id + " ," + date + " ," + body + " ,"
                            + phoneNumber);

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
            WriteToFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void WriteToFile() {
        try {
            CSV export = new CSV();
            export.generateCSVFile(exportBuffer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Create CSV Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CSV extends SMSbackup {

    public static ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static File rootFolder;
    public static File root;
    private static String subFolderName;
    private static String fileName;
    public boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    public boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

    public CSV() 
    {
        checkStorage();

        if(mExternalStorageAvailable == true && mExternalStorageWriteable == true)
        {
            root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SMSMonitor/", null);
            subFolderName = GetSubFolder();
            fileName = getFileName();
        }
    }

    public void checkStorage()
    {
        CharSequence text;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
        {
            text = "SD card is Read and Write";
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;

        } 
        else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
        {
            text = "SD Card is Read Only";
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            text = "Something else is wrong...";
        }
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SmsBackupActivity.defaultInstance, text, duration);
        //toast.show();
    }

    public void generateCSVFile(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        root = new File(rootFolder + "/SMSMonitor/" + subFolderName, fileName);

        try 
        {
            FileWriter write = new FileWriter(root);

            write.append("ID, Date, Address, Body");
            write.append('\n');

            for (String s : list)
            {
                write.append(s);
                write.append('\n');
            }
            write.flush();
            write.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static String getFileName()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String fileName = "Backup_" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString() + ".csv";

        return fileName;
    }

    private static String GetSubFolder()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        subFolderName = sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

        return subFolderName;
    }

}
```

Possible Stack trace?:

```
    // Compiled from ThreadGroup.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class java.lang.ThreadGroup implements java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler {

  // Method descriptor #9 (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public ThreadGroup(java.lang.String name);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 5]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: name index: 1 type: java.lang.String

  // Method descriptor #17 (Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public ThreadGroup(java.lang.ThreadGroup parent, java.lang.String name);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 6]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: parent index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: name index: 2 type: java.lang.String

  // Method descriptor #20 ()I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public int activeCount();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 7]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #20 ()I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public int activeGroupCount();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 8]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #23 (Z)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public boolean allowThreadSuspension(boolean b);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 9]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: b index: 1 type: boolean

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void checkAccess();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 10]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void destroy();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 11]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #30 ([Ljava/lang/Thread;)I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public int enumerate(java.lang.Thread[] threads);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 12]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: threads index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread[]

  // Method descriptor #33 ([Ljava/lang/Thread;Z)I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public int enumerate(java.lang.Thread[] threads, boolean recurse);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 13]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: threads index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread[]
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: recurse index: 2 type: boolean

  // Method descriptor #35 ([Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;)I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public int enumerate(java.lang.ThreadGroup[] groups);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 14]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: groups index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup[]

  // Method descriptor #38 ([Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Z)I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public int enumerate(java.lang.ThreadGroup[] groups, boolean recurse);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 15]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: groups index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup[]
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: recurse index: 2 type: boolean

  // Method descriptor #20 ()I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final int getMaxPriority();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 16]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #41 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final java.lang.String getName();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 17]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #43 ()Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final java.lang.ThreadGroup getParent();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 18]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void interrupt();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 19]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #46 ()Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final boolean isDaemon();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 20]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #46 ()Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public synchronized boolean isDestroyed();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 21]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void list();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 22]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #50 (Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public final boolean parentOf(java.lang.ThreadGroup g);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 23]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: g index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void resume();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 24]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #54 (Z)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public final void setDaemon(boolean isDaemon);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 25]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: isDaemon index: 1 type: boolean

  // Method descriptor #56 (I)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public final void setMaxPriority(int newMax);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 26]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: newMax index: 1 type: int

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void stop();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 27]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #27 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public final void suspend();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 28]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #41 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public java.lang.String toString();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 29]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup

  // Method descriptor #63 (Ljava/lang/Thread;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public void uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread t, java.lang.Throwable e);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 30]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: t index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: e index: 2 type: java.lang.Throwable

  Inner classes:
    [inner class info: #7 java/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler, outer class info: #76 java/lang/Thread
     inner name: #78 UncaughtExceptionHandler, accessflags: 1545 public abstract static]
}
```

Console:

```
    [2011-07-04 17:59:32 - SMSbackupv1] Android Launch!
[2011-07-04 17:59:32 - SMSbackupv1] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-04 17:59:32 - SMSbackupv1] Performing com.SMS.Backup.SMSbackupv1Activity activity launch
[2011-07-04 17:59:32 - SMSbackupv1] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Test'
[2011-07-04 17:59:32 - SMSbackupv1] Uploading SMSbackupv1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-07-04 17:59:33 - SMSbackupv1] Installing SMSbackupv1.apk...
[2011-07-04 17:59:37 - SMSbackupv1] Success!
[2011-07-04 17:59:37 - SMSbackupv1] Starting activity com.SMS.Backup.SMSbackupv1Activity on device emulator-5554
[2011-07-04 17:59:41 - SMSbackupv1] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.SMS.Backup/.SMSbackupv1Activity }
[2011-07-04 17:59:42 - SMSbackupv1] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.SMS.Backup' on port 8621
```

DDMS Nothing
Debug window shows:
[image]

the application loads once shows the application stopped unexpectedly error then the debugger shows the window above i can step over it all and it goes on for ever then the error shows again :/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't the error that you're getting. The warning "Source not found" applies to Eclipse's attempts to debug your crash by following the stack trace. If you paste in the stack trace that you're getting, we might be able to help.

Comment: i think ive added the stack trace i think? im used to using net beans and not eclipse so im not entirely sure where the sack trace is? :s

Comment: Whoops, ok! Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581837/android-debugging-with-logcat-and-emulator-is-it-possible

Comment: sorry that didnt word that quite rite :P what i ment to say is im using eclipse but im not familiar with the debugging system and not sure if it is the correct stack trace :s

Comment: Probably my bad, sorry! In Eclipse, open the DDMS perspective. Then with the device selected in the Devices pane, look at the Logcat pane and scroll to the bottom. Red error messages will appear whenever an application crashes on that device.

Comment: this is what i don't understand they isnt any error messages in ether logcat or the DDMS windows when it crashes i have even tried putting break points on the starting methods and they don't even trigger.

Comment: Can you post the final few dozen lines of the log immediate preceding and after the crash?

Comment: That's not the DDMS perspective! :) If you don't have that perspective available by default, go to Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> DDMS. Or you can click on the LogCat tab in that bottom pane in the screenshot that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

This type warning getting when you debug application that's something missing on your .xml file. this may be your layout file or manifest file. double check it out your .xml file.
if you can see logcat then you can easily find the problem.

For Example: **Source not found and open Instrumentation.class** then it probably u didn't add your activity class in android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that many of us would be facing and this problem may not be applicable only to testing the app but also to the app that you install on your device.
If the Developer has deviced app for a particular layout or has not changed the XMLs for all layouts, it will throw error in some devices.

Android has 4 Layouts (most of us know)

Layout
Layout-small
Layout-large
Layout-xlarge

The issue with me was that I made the change in the XML file in the layout-small folder which supports 2.7 inches. 
I ran the Emulator which was again for 2.7 inches and worked absolutely fine.
Now when I exported the signed application and tested in the device, it fails. The reason was that I did not make the necessary changes in the Layout folder.
My device was expecting some fields for the calculation that was in the main.xml file for layout -small but not in the layout version installed.
So couple of things you should do.
1) When testing the application, do create only 1 folder (layout with all the xml files) and that way you will be able to test the FUNCTIONALITY of your app on all devices.
2) if you have created all the Layout folders and then make change in any XML file, do make sure that the change(s) is(are) cascaded to all folders.

Happy development...