# Android MediaPlayer hangs my app

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I've got quite a problem with MediaPLayer,
i have really no idea, why this code doesn't work!
Btw. it doesn't work either on Samsung Galaxy Ace or emulator :(
just getting "The application org.me.androidapplication11(process org.me.androidapplication11) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."
help please!

```
package org.me.androidapplication11;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.as);
    mPlayer.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug your app using logcat. I don't know if you're developing in Eclipse, but if you are, [this](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) link might help you.

Comment: im developing in NetBeans
anyway thanks for logcat idea :P
ill try it.

Comment: Then you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581837/android-debugging-with-logcat-and-emulator-is-it-possible :)

Comment: A quick and dirty sollution to get the type of exception could be to surround it with a try/catch and showing the exeption in a Toast.. Toast.makeText(this, the_exception_caught, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: well, the error is:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
File res/raw/as.mid from drawable Resource ID
#0x7f030000
what does it mean? o_O
the file is in proper folder

Comment: omg, it works at eclipse and it doesnt work in netbeans :/
Please some1 help, i'd like to develop in NetBeans enviroment :(

Comment: after all i've switched to eclipse.