# Android exception corrupted pad block

Tags: android, exception, encryption, aes

Hi I have problem in my android application. I wrote client which used tcp and udp. Data are encrypt by AES. BUT my application return exception when i try to receive datagram.
this is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
     {
         try
            {

             udp = new DatagramSocket(2500);

                 boolean flagaBYE = true;

                 String w = "";
                while(flagaBYE)
                {
                            byte[] receiveData= new byte[1024];

                                DatagramPacket pakiet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                                udp.receive(pakiet);

                    String wiadomosc = new String(pakiet.getData(),"utf-8");
                                publishProgress(wiadomosc);
                               String szyfr = main.preferences.getString("SZYFR_TCP", "");
                               if(!szyfr.equals("1"))
                               {
                                   Encryptor enc = new Encryptor(getKeyBytes(key), getCode());
                                   wiadomosc = enc.decrypt(wiadomosc);

                               }
```

My exception is pad block corrupted
I generate key like this:

```
 String key = "tojestkluczwlasnie";
```

And next parse string to byte[]

```
public static byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
      return keyBytes;
    }
```

Comment: How? I use netbeans and emulator and ex.message is corrupted pad block

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581837/android-debugging-with-logcat-and-emulator-is-it-possible/4763346#4763346 or just launch ddms by hand

Comment: no error. Only warming http://wklej.org/id/858662/

Comment: so I don't know why is this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should not treat bytes as being UTF-8 strings, and you should not treat passwords if they are keys. Its likely that you lose information during the transformations between the data formats (encoding/decoding).