# Android - why does getResources for application path to use in Intent causes startActivity to fail?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Instead of hardcoding the package name for each activity I thought I'd place it on the string resources and create an Intent as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.path)+"ABOUT");
startActivity(i);
```

R.string.path is defined as follows:

```
<string name="path">com.myproject.cvd_2009.</string>
```

This always causes the emulator to fail when calling starting an activity defined like so.

If I create an intent without using the resources, the application on the emulator works as expected. (Untrue the below actually failed, I believe it was due to issues (1) and (2) in the solution).

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String s = "com.myproject.cvd_2009.QUESTIONNAIRE1";// getResources().getString(R.string.path)+"QUESTIONNAIRE1";
    Intent i = new Intent(s);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here is the questionnaire1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/black"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/q1"
        android:padding="10pt"
        android:paddingTop="25pt"
    />
    <RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:paddingLeft="10pt"
        android:paddingBottom="10pt"
    >
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_male"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/male"
                     android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                     android:layout_weight="50"
        />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_female"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/female"
                     android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                     android:layout_weight="50"
        />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/q2"
        android:padding="10pt"
    />
    <Spinner

        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/age_select"
    />


    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:gravity="bottom"

    >   

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="onClick"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="onClick"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone please explain why I cannot use the resources when creating an Intent?

Updated to include Stacktrace from Logcat now included, I see there is a null pointer exception which is not being caught, I'm not sure why the ComponentInfo is duplicating the com.myproject.cvd_2009 for the activity? I presume that is the reason for the exception

```
06-02 12:17:43.102 W/dalvikvm( 1418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject.cvd_2009/com.myproject.cvd_2009.Questionnaire1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:443)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:430)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at com.myproject.cvd_2009.Questionnaire1.setSpinner(Questionnaire1.java:161)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at com.myproject.cvd_2009.Questionnaire1.onCreate(Questionnaire1.java:48)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
06-02 12:17:43.132 E/AndroidRuntime( 1418):     ... 11 more
06-02 12:17:43.172 W/ActivityManager(  276):   Force finishing activity com.myproject.cvd_2009/.Questionnaire1
06-02 12:17:43.172 W/ActivityManager(  276):   Force finishing activity com.myproject.cvd_2009/.CvdFramingham
06-02 12:17:43.684 W/ActivityManager(  276): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41cf8380 u0 com.myproject.cvd_2009/.Questionnaire1}
```

SOLUTION (Requires More Explanation,):

(1) I had some Toast objects created, but I never displayed them. By removing the Toast statements which were not being used might of helped.

(2) Found a case of a nested attribute in the layout of an xml, so I removed the nested attribute:

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

(3) This is actually not the issue

```
Intent i = new Intent(getResources().getString(R.string.path)+"ABOUT");
startActivity(i);
```

This just baffled me because when I commented out the startActivity the app never failed so I presumed it was due to my Intent definition. However I have a mix of both methods detailed above now working. I'd like to thank everyone who mentioned logcat - I now have that set up and I will use that for debugging.

Comment: What is your logcat said?

Comment: Can you try using `String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.path), "ABOUT")` with `<string name="path">com.myproject.cvd_2009.%1$s</string>`

Comment: Why do you have the path as a string resource actually? I guess your path is something that should not be translated into various languages.

Comment: I haven't set up logcat. I am new to Android, my IDE is Netbeans. I am reading about it here. Where do I do I make the change so that logcat appears?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581837/android-debugging-with-logcat-and-emulator-is-it-possible/4763346#4763346

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(this, getResources().getString(R.string.path)+"ABOUT");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: correction: this does work. However, I'm actually a little baffled at why my code wasn't working in the first place, but I believe it was related to one of the two points I suggested above. if anyone could elaborate that would be much appreciated.