# my android app runs fine in the emulator, but when i publish it it's wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, export, emulation

i have an app that has a few checkboxes in the settings and then compiles a remote sql based on the checkboxes selected. i ran it in the emulator and it's fine. but then i exported it and published it as an app, and the same checked boxes aren't being passed correctly. i wonder if it's a caching issue or something. tried deleting the apks a few times and republish but to no avail. i "fake-edited" the source java and then export again, still no difference.

i'm kind of new to eclipse but is there a force build option? i only see build-automatically option under project but not sure how i can make sure that the apk exported is the same as run in the emulator

*edit* the emulator is version 1.5, and my phone is nexus one running 2.1- not sure if that makes a difference

thanks

Comment: Project -> Clean will rebuild your project.

Comment: Unlikely to be a build issue in my view. The 1.5/2.1 issue may make a difference. Try the 2.1 emulator maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jim mentioned, always make sure you test your app on the same version emulator as you intend to use it. If it's going to be put on the Market, then make sure you test it on several versions. For example, test on at least v1.5, v1.6 and v2.1. Make sure you use different screen sizes as well for each of these; that's not going to be your problem here, but it will show you whether you've coded your XML files properly.

Another thing you can try is to enable your phone to output log messages, and then you can see if something odd is happening on your phone. I don't have a phone with v2.1, but according to the emulator, this is where that option is: home screen -> menu -> settings -> applications -> development -> enable USB debugging. Once you've done that, restart Eclipse, plug your phone in, and you should start seeing log messages. Restarting Eclipse isn't always needed, but LogCat sometimes gets confused when you've got multiple emulators/real phones trying to output debugging messages. (If you don't know how to enable LogCat, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android/2552801#2552801).)