# eclipse null pointer exception debug

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following code in a few activities and it reads and parses XML files fine but in two activities when reading small XML files I get a null pointer exception and can't figure out what the problem is:

```
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if ((eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) ||
        (eventType == XmlResourceParser.TEXT)) {
        // Get the name of the tag (eg scores or score)
        String strName = xmlSymptoms.getName();
        if (helpFound == 1){
            helpText  = xmlSymptoms.getText();
            helpFound = 0;
        } else if (strName.equals("string") && (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG)) {
            helpFound = 1;
        }

    }
    eventType = xmlSymptoms.next();
}
```

The null pointer exception occurs when I am reading in "`<string>`" which I am able to read in with the same code in other activities.  In this activity, I am able to read in the other XML tokens fine until I get to "`<string>`".

Here is my debug window

Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2628
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679
    ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running)

I have LogCat running, but nothing shows up in it.

Here is some XML that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>A</key>
<array>
        <string>ABANDONED, feeling:     </string>
        <string>ABSCESS:        </string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and here is some XML that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>HOWTOTAKE</key>  
  <array>
  <string> Put two pellets in 8 oz bottle of water.</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

One last note:  When I get to the "`<string>`" field, getName() returns "null" instead of "string".  Obviously trying to tell me something, I just can't figure out why "null" is returned.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: What line does the NPE occur on?

Comment: can you give an example of the xml that works and one that does not work?

Comment: JRL - the line of the Activity code where the NPE occurs on is:


          } else if (strName.equals("string") && (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG)) {

Comment: yaourt - I added the working and non-working XML to the original post.

Comment: You're not seeing the actual NPE line in the debugger trace.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android/2555489#2555489 for an explanation of why.

Comment: @fadden - I read through the link you provided.  Can you tell me why I am not seeing the actual NPE line in the debugger trace?  Do I have to stop the emulator first?

Comment: The link should have taken you to my comments on a similar complaint, explaining why it works the way it does and what you can do about it.  In short, Eclipse is breaking on the re-throw, not the original throw.  Add an Eclipse exception breakpoint on caught+uncaught NullPointerException and run it again.

Comment: @fadden - I added a breakpoint on caught+uncaught NullPointerException and ran it again, and the Debug window and the LogCat window doesn't give me any information about why there is a NullPointerException at a given line number. How can I get more information about the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  Since I am looking for XmlResourceParser.TEXT, strName.equals("string") is null when (eventType == XmlResourceParser.TEXT) is true.  Changing the code to only check for (strName.equals("string") when (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) is true, fixed the problem as shown in the code below:

```
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if ((eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) ||
        (eventType == XmlResourceParser.TEXT)) {
        // Get the name of the tag (eg scores or score)
        String strName = xmlSymptoms.getName();
        if (helpFound == 1){
            helpText  = xmlSymptoms.getText();
            helpFound = 0;
        } else if ( (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG)) {
            if (strName.equals("string") ){
                helpFound = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    eventType = xmlSymptoms.next();
}
}
```