# How do you debug Android inEclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, exception, logging

Try the following:

1. Create a HelloWorld application.
2. Add a Log statement to the end of onCreate:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("HelloWorldActivity.onCreate()", "setContentView() completed");
    }
```

1. Place a breakpoint on the Log statement.
2. Run the app in the emulator and note it works and step to see the Logged entry in the LogCat window of Eclipse.
3. Change the HelloWorldActivity to extend from ListActivity instead of Activity.

   ```
   public class HelloWorldActivity extends ListActivity {
   ```
4. Run the app in the emulator again and note it fails to reach the Log statement.

My question is NOT why this fails.  My question is, how would you go about debugging this failure?  All I see in the Eclipse Debug pane is a RuntimeException.  I see LogCat has a bunch of messages, but it's huge and I've searched it but can't find anything to indicate what's wrong or where in my code the exception happened.  I can't find a way to display the message inside the RuntimeException or a stack trace to know which line of code initiated the exception.

I assume there must be better ways to use the tools to find errors, but I'm new and can't seem to figure out a better way to debug besides wrapping everything I code in a try/catch.  I would have expected to find a message in LogCat generated by the throwing of the exception.  I would have expected the Debug window to allow you to inspect the exception's contents.  I'm not saying that such techniques don't exist, I'm saying I'm having trouble figuring out as a beginner how to debug and asking what techniques do exist and how do I use them?

So, simply put:

- How would you find this error if you didn't already know what was causing it?
- What techniques would you use to find out the root cause?
- How would you go about inspecting the Exception's details?
- Generally, how do you find problems in your Android code using Eclipse?

Multiple suggestions and discussion are welcomed.  :)

I would have included my LogCat contents, but it's so large that's not reasonable.  You should be able to easily reproduce this yourself, so I left it out.  It is possible something is in LogCat to help me, but because it's so large with even running a small program, I would need a hint as to what to search for and how to interpret it when hitting an exception thrown from an API call.  I see other posts that state something should be in LogCat, which while might be true, I'm not finding anything myself.  If you think something should be in LogCat, please run the test yourself and copy the lines into your response that I should be finding.

Thanks.

========

Summary techniques list so far is as follows:

Invasive Techniques:
1. Place a Toast in code locations where you want to see you you've executed.
2. Place try/catch around code where you think there's a possibility of an Exception being thrown. 
3. Comment out code and recompile and retest.

Non-Invasive Techniques:
1. Use the debugger. Breakpoints, variable inspection...
2. Monkey stress tester.
3. Download Android source library.
4. Use LogCat filters to see if a "Caused By" is listed.

Unclear if Available:
1. Debug version of Android library that has additional logging, assertions or other additional help. 
2. Ability to inspect an Exception in Eclipse through the Debug pane or other techniques.
3. A way to define a more global try/catch exception handler.
4. Ability to debug through the Android library source code.

Not Available:
1. A non-invasive way to view the contents of an Exception or where the Exception happened.

Comment: For inspecting the exception details i often use the Expressions window in debug mode (Window>Show View>Expressions) to check values. This is handy when checking the exception as exception.getMesage() doesn't always return a message (i.e. null) In Debug mode whilst in a break point right click on the variable and select "watch". You have to step over the exception to watch it.

Comment: The Problems window in eclipse will show you pre-compile time errors, and also strict warnings. (Window>Show View>other  ...Problems)

Comment: LogCat is miss leading at first. The filter works on the Message and not your Log tags. To create a custom filter you should use the LogCat menu and select the "Create filter" option. Here you can filter by tag and pid giving you much more granular control. It also appears in a tabbed window. Very usefull to hide system events. These messages really help now what worked last, but might not show you the error. so flick back to show all system events. (or log by pid)

Answer (score 2):

hey, 
Ineresting question. Well, first tip, you can filter what logcat tells you. For instance, you make it just show you errors by clickin in the red (e). 
It also tells you where the error happened if you run your app in debug mode. It can either point you directly to your code or to android sdk. Knowing what android package caused the error is a big help.

These two just pop into my mind. hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, the red (e) seems to filter, so that's a big help.  Do you happen to know if Exceptions are supposed to log an (e)rror, warning, info?  Since I don't see any, I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like.  If it's an (e)rror, your suggestion would cut down the number of messages to significantly.

Comment: Also, regarding "debug mode".  Is this just where you click on the bug icon instead of simply running or is there some debug library I should be loading.  I'm more of a Windows programmer and when I work with MFC, they have a debug version of the library so you can actually trace that source code.  Is there something like that with Android/Eclipse?

Comment: I'd give you a vote thumbs up, but Apparently I need to be rated higher to do that.  Sorry.  :(

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and found the following by Steve H. that helped out:

> What happens is that when the debugger
>   is attached, the exception logs don't
>   get posted to LogCat until you
>   terminate the application from within
>   the Debug perspective. This happens
>   because the application doesn't
>   actually crash until the debugger
>   detaches. – Steve H Mar 31 at 15:47
>
> ------ yup, that did it. Now I see the same exception. AFTER I let the
>   program run through it's full crash
>   and exit process. It should display
>   that info when it halts my program and
>   brings up the IDE debugger screens.
>   Not leave me wondering and wasting my
>   time with more clicking around.
>   Eclipse has a long way to go it seems
>   to compete with the likes of Visual
>   Studio. Let's hope my patience for it
>   outlasts my project. Thanks for the
>   feedback. :) – Sebastian Dwornik Mar
>   31 at 17:35

Link to Question: [What's wrong with debugging in Eclipse on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Generally if anything throws an exception then you should probably be catering for that situation anyway, however putting try/catch blocks is a decent way of finding the specific problem.
I've found that if you don't put something in the catch block then you can't evaluate the exception in the watch variables window in eclipse. So i always put a Log call in and set a break point on that line.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }catch(Exception exception)
    {
        // put break point on line below so you can evaluate exception in debug mode.
        Log.e(TAG, "Set content exception "+ exception.getMessage());
        // note some exceptions return null on getMessage();
    }
    Log.d("HelloWorldActivity.onCreate()", "setContentView() completed");
}
```

So if your stack trace is huge then this will help. Other developers have also found that getting the source code for the sdk means you can view where the error is thrown in the main sdk code. I've not done this though.

Comment: Having the source code would be helpful.  Very Helpful!  I knew it was available, but I wasn't sure you could use the debugger to trace through it.  That would be extremely helpful.  Is there a description somewhere on how to integrate it into your debugging session?

Comment: I understand your point about having try/catch around anything that could throw an exception.  However, there are times when you're simply doing testing code and putting that around each little section of code is very cumbersome while getting the basics down.  Also, if you read my case, that exception should never happen once the code is fixed.  All the same, good point and one of the techniques I mentioned for finding the problem.  I take it there's no way then to get the contents of an exception without putting try/catch code?

Comment: If doing test code, put all of it in a single try catch, then add more for specific cases you do want to manage. At least that way you can save time when an exception is thrown, and its not to much effort.

Comment: i found the standard stack trace displayed in debug mode to be some what indecipherable, hence using try/catch, i have however become accustomed to what the error is by reading the first most errors. Most commonly its either; Not in manifest file, activity or permission. Null pointer is generally either casting wrong, scope issue with inline listener code or asset not having been attached or id changed. You start to get to know what the problem is as soon as you've encountered it.

Comment: Can you please explain how to get to the "standard stack trace"?  I'm unable to get any stack trace once an Exception happens and this would be helpful to know once an exception happens, where it's located.

Comment: How do you put a single try/catch to cover everything?  It seems most code is in callbacks, so I'm unclear where I could put such code that would act as a backstop to all otherwise uncaught exceptions.  If this were Windows/C++, I would add it to my main() function and/or install a global exception handler using set_unexpected() and other similar API's to set error handlers.

Comment: I think log cat displays the stack trace by default. Otherwise in debug mode its in the Debug Window. without a break point your pretty much stuck as to being able to do anything as normally the exception is thrown from one of the SDK classes.

Comment: You can't put a try catch to catch everything as far as i'm aware. But you can put try catch around code in specifc methods your working in perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions not caught with try/catch are errors and break the normal flow of the program.

Running in debug mode is just clicking in the bug button. I don't know if there are any "special" debug libraries. But when working with android, all "libraries" are open source so you can pretty much view anything.

The good thing about debug mode is that when an error occurs, your app is frozen right in the limbo when the error occurs. You can set set breakpoints, change your code on the fly while your program is running, which is great (Well, you can't make drastic changes like changing a method name).

The way you treat bugs and errors in android, however,  can be a bit different from .NET, since the model in each one is different.

When programming to windows, apps work like small islands. You have a much direct control over the code flow (ie: you can call a modal dialog to freeze codeflow while a user inputs some data) and you can make a totally functional program using just one thread.  In android almost everything runs in it's own sync. And your app must be prepared to handle stuff like receiving a phone call in the middle of execution. So, you can apply this model to debugging also: [Errors (that happen due to unforsen circumstances) tend to propagate much more than in other development ambient](https://engineering.purdue.edu/dcsl/publications/papers/2010/android_issre10_submit.pdf). The way those errors are handled is different too: this is apparent when you realize that your app still runs even after throwing an exception.

Some more useful tips: 
You have a very powerful tool called Monkey, a stress tool that generates "pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-
level events".

LogCat indicates you the "cause" of the error. The line usually starts with Caused By. If you're interested in the cause rather than the consequence, you can further filter your error reports looking for "Caused by".

Last but not least, I find the old method of commenting lines and see what happens very useful to figure things out.

hope it helps

Comment: Yup, I saw the "Caused By" in a different post, but when I searched for it in my LogCat it didn't show up.  Did you try my example and see if you get a "Caused By" for you?  I'm curious if I should be seeing something I'm missing.

Comment: It doesn't seem that I get my code frozen when the error happens in my example.  It seems like the Exception is thrown and since I don't have an exception handler, my code simply exits past the Log statement.  Maybe I'm missing some setting (ex.  Break On Exception) available in the debugger?

Comment: Commenting out lines is a good suggestion.  I've been doing that quite a bit.  Kind of slow and cumbersome, but definitely effective.  Once I get all the suggestions for this post, I'm going to gather them and collect them all.  Maybe I repost them in a blog or something to share with others.  Thanks. :)

Comment: In your specific code, your program stops at the first activity that is created, main. So basically only super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
is run. Try this: (1) Create a new project (2) add 2 buttons in main (3) create another activity with some error (4) bind one button to the second activty (5) bind the second button to a Toat.makeText (6) run the application and click the first button... an error will occur. An alert will appear, you click OK, your app wil keep running and if you click button 2 it works. This is valid too if you button 2 would use some kind of return from activity 2.