# Debugging Android RuntimeException - Before my code even executes

Tags: android

I'm not new to Java but new to the Android platform. I'm finding one of the platforms shortcomings to be meaningful feedback on runtime crashes. Fine in user code where breakpoints apply, but I have a crash on first run that is preventing my project from starting, and I can't see a way to track it down. Can anyone shed any light?

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8626]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2585  
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
        ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Same on emulator and device.

I've seen reports of crashes like these being caused by inflation of invalid XML so I have removed all XML's and resources from my project, almost one by one, and the same error remains! Are there any tricks or instrumentation I can apply to try and get a more meaningful error message? Thanks.

Comment: Post some code, post your manifest. You say it crashes before your code even executes. How do you know that? So when does it crash? While you're thinking about running it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer to gleaning more information in these situations. This page has some very useful information: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg79386.html

By opening the 'Variables' tab in the Debug section of Eclipse's views I could see there was a value named 'e' presumably for 'exception' with the value 'ClassNotFoundException'. By clicking on it I saw a fuller description saying the class that couldn't be found. It was my main Activity, which I'd renamed on a late night before, and forgotten about. *Facepalm* Hope this info helps someone!

Comment: If the application was exiting, the log output viewable from DDMS or "adb logcat" would show the full trace.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android/2555489#2555489 .

Comment: I came across this when trying to debug a similar crash. My variables tab shows nothing, but the specific type of exception can be found by setting an Eclipse breakpoint for uncaught exceptions. When the program under debug breaks due to the uncaught RuntimeException, the breakpoint window will show the specific type of exception caught like this: AcceptPendingException [Suspend VM]: uncaught. It doesn't necessarily solve the problem of knowing the cause, but it's a step further in the process.