# Store editText value to another activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have more than 3 edittext. When i enter something inside edittext i need to save this to another screen using SharedPreferences. I used Intent before pass editText value to another Activity. But i need to save editText value later for editing purpose.

code:

Activity :

```
 et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

            et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

   String[] day_array = new String[] {et.getText().toString(), et1.getText().toString() };

                  editor.putInt("array_size", day_array.length);
                  for (int i = 0; i < day_array.length; i++)
                      editor.putString("array_" + i, day_array[i]);
                  editor.commit();


                  Intent intent = new Intent(Save.this, Get.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 1:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);

  int size = preferences.getInt("array_size", 0);
      String[] Display_Room_array = new String[size];

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

          name = preferences.getString("array_" + i, Display_Room_array[i]);
          Display_Room_array[i] = name;

          txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
          txt.setText(Display_Room_array[i]);

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
```

Comment: Save it into SqliteDB

Comment: what is issue you getting. post errorlog in case

Comment: What is your problem here ? it seems you send it to a new activity and save it in sharedpref as it should be...

Comment: After entering some text inside editText click save button i got confirmation Perspective switch window then Debug mode it indicates this line SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

Comment: @Guian: You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class with Strings as static and save the text values there.
Also put setter and getter functions in that class.
In the next activity just create object of that class and get those values.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't get what you want?

you said that you want to save 3 edit texts value in preferences ok?

you can do this in first activity too!

but if you are saying that you want to save edittext value in other activities then you should use intent.put extra to pass values to next activity and in that you can store values in shared preferences! what a big deal in that?

Comment: see my question. I used intent.putextra and used sharedPreference.

Comment: When click save button it goes to debug mode displays the confirmation Perspective switch window

Comment: then take snap shot with print scren or if you have mobile with camera feature then take picture of log and post here

Answer (score 0):

You can save some value in `SharedPreferences` and access that latter as follow...

```
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Save.this, Get.class);
            String[] myStrings = new String[] {txtt.getText().toString(),et.getText().toString() ,txtt1.getText().toString(),et1.getText().toString() };
                intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);


                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("default", MODE_PRIVATE);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                  editor.putString("text1",txtt.getText().toString());
                  editor.putString("text2",et.getText().toString());
           .....
           ......   
                  editor.commit();


         startActivity(intent);
```

In next Activity you can access that preferences as follow..

```
.......
......

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("default", MODE_PRIVATE);

String text1= preference.getString("text1"," ");
String text2= preference.getString("text2"," ");
....
.....

txt.setText(text1);
txt2.setText(text2);
```

Comment: getting some error ? or value not saved in preferences ? post error in logcat.

Comment: When click save button it goes to debug mode displays the confirmation Perspective switch window

Comment: may be there is any breakpoint in your code, check that. also check perspective setting of IDE.

Comment: refer these S.O. discussion for more information about this proble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330115/debugging-android-runtimeexception-before-my-code-even-executes  or here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android/2555489#2555489

Comment: when i use this line String text1= preference.getString("text1"); I got error. so i used to String text1= preferences.getString("text1", " ");

Comment: yes you are right, i have also edit the code. Now have you fixed your problem ?

Comment: No. Same problem getting