# following android game development guide and when I try to deploy it on a virtual test device or my own android phone it doesnt work

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment

I'm following an android game development guide and when I try to deploy it on a virtual test device or my own android phone it doesnt work. Im using ---->[this](http://www.kilobolt.com/create-an-android-game-from-scratch-or-port-your-existing-game.html)<---- guide (I followed everything from the previous guides) and I just finished with step 4 and I try to run it on both the virtual test device and my phone (both which worked before) but now the virtual device wont show up in the Android device chooser, and my phone does show up but when I try to deploy it I get these results and it doesn't do anything to my phone:

```
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] Android Launch!
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] Performing sync
[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-09 22:34:09 - AndroidGame] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-05-09 22:34:09 - AndroidGame] \AndroidGame\bin\AndroidGame.apk installed on device
[2013-05-09 22:34:09 - AndroidGame] Done!
```

also, when I click "Launch a new Android Virtual Device" with the settings told to me in the guide, I get these results:

```
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] ------------------------------
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] Android Launch!
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] Performing sync
[2013-05-09 22:42:15 - AndroidGame] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-09 22:42:24 - AndroidGame] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'GalaxyNexus'
[2013-05-09 22:42:24 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration.
```

help?

ok I clicked reset adb in DDMS and I got these in logcat under error:

```
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): dhcpcd has parameter opt=n(110)
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): read_config() enter
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): read_config() file=NULL
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): read_config() ifname=NULL
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): read_config() ssid=NULL
05-10 19:34:25.377: E/dhcpcd(16431): read_config() profile=NULL
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(16431): opening file /system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd.conf
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(16431): add_options() enter
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(16431): parse_option() enter, opt=n(110)
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(16431): optind=2
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(16431): sending signal 14 to pid 3503
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): n=-1, errno=4
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): new loop begin!
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): now.tv_sec=1368239665, now.tv_usec=396431; timeouts.tv_sec=1368241393, timeouts.tv_usec=429503
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): nfds=1
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): n=1, errno=4
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): e->fd=9
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): handle_signal() enter sig=14
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): received SIGALRM, renewing
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: renewing lease of 192.168.1.101
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: sending REQUEST (xid 0x758c1751), next in 2.64 seconds
05-10 19:34:25.387: E/dhcpcd(3503): open_sockets() enter iface->raw_fd=-1, iface->udp_fd=-1, iface->addr.s_addr=1694607552
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_event() fd=13
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): send_message() add timeout.
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_tv() queue=0, when.tv_sec=1, when.tv_usec=1637134
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): new loop begin!
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): now.tv_sec=1368239665, now.tv_usec=411752; timeouts.tv_sec=1368239667, timeouts.tv_usec=1048886
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): nfds=2
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): n=1, errno=4
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): e->fd=13
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: acknowledged 192.168.1.101 from 192.168.1.1
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): delete_q_timeout() queue=0
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): close_sockets() enter iface->arp_fd=-1, iface->raw_fd=13, iface->udp_fd=14
05-10 19:34:25.407: E/dhcpcd(3503): delete_event() fd=13
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): bind_interface() enter
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): close_sockets() enter iface->arp_fd=-1, iface->raw_fd=-1, iface->udp_fd=-1
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): delete_q_timeout() queue=0
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: leased 192.168.1.101 for 86400 seconds
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_sec() queue=0, when=43200
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_tv() queue=0, when.tv_sec=43200, when.tv_usec=0
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_sec() queue=0, when=75600
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_tv() queue=0, when.tv_sec=75600, when.tv_usec=0
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_sec() queue=0, when=86400
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): add_q_timeout_tv() queue=0, when.tv_sec=86400, when.tv_usec=0
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: adding IP address 192.168.1.101/24
05-10 19:34:25.427: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: writing lease `/data/misc/dhcp/dhcpcd-wlan0.lease'
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): wlan0: executing `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks', reason RENEW
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): make_env() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): auto_ip_enabled() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): configure_env() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): !env
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): configure_env() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): append_config() enter, config=0
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): configure_env() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): !env
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): make_env() e=15
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): configure_env() enter
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): append_config() enter, config=0
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): path=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
05-10 19:34:25.437: E/dhcpcd(3503): exec_script() enter
05-10 19:34:25.687: E/dhcpcd(3503): new loop begin!
05-10 19:34:25.687: E/dhcpcd(3503): now.tv_sec=1368239665, now.tv_usec=430644; timeouts.tv_sec=1368282865, timeouts.tv_usec=430553
05-10 19:34:25.687: E/dhcpcd(3503): nfds=1
05-10 20:08:31.720: A/libc(18008): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000070 (code=1)
05-10 20:08:31.970: A/libc(18027): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000070 (code=1)
```

am I allowed to make a repost so more people will see this thread?

Answer (score 0):

[2013-05-09 22:34:05 - AndroidGame] No Launcher activity found!

Are you sure, that in your AndroidManifest.xml activity has this intent-filter?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Like it is described in part 4 in guide

Comment: oops -_- it didnt say to change that. i shoulda just copy pasted everything

Comment: ok the screen turned black on my phone but then said "Unfortunately, sample game has stopped" =/

Comment: Are you familiar with LogCat? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html If you use Eclipse or IDEA you can show it in separate tab, like console window. Actually you can see information about crash in LogCat. Copy error message here

Comment: i have it but every time it does that it says absolutely nothing in logcat

Comment: First of all, you should set up LogCat. It's very difficult to develop applications without any information about errors. Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552568/whats-wrong-with-debugging-in-eclipse-on-android/2552801#2552801. Note that some rare devices has log turned off by default. So, search in google if anyone have had problems with device you run app on.

Comment: my device has usb debugging enabled, and i searched metro zte logcat and i just get links to download it as an app.. how can I turn it on?

Comment: oh wow i just had to click all messages (no filters) in the saved filters box and it showed like a million of them O.o

Comment: wait I cleared them and tried deploying the thing again and when I got the error on the phone it wouldnt show anything in logcat :[

Comment: these errors are not from your application. Try to set filters (package filter) and show errors only from your app.